# Flask Server-side Sessions lost using google-oauth

Tags: python, session, flask, google-oauth, flask-session

I have an existing flask app that uses the flask session to store data.  I have just integrated google oauth into the app, and this worked.  The issue occurred after change the basic flask session to use flask-session for server-side sessions ( Mainly for needing more that the 4kb limit on the session).  At this point I get a never ending redirect loop.

I am running this locally using pycharm.  I have created a clientID and secret in google API's and added http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback as an authorized redirect URL.  I have also added https://example.com/oauth2calback with a local DNS record pointing to a server i am deploying this on ( via docker container)

Locally, everything seems to work, even when implementing server-side sessions. However once i have deployed this and enter https://example.com, after the google authentication, i get caught in an infinite redirect loop.

```
import ...
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
# Get if this is either dev env or prod env
# then set appropriate dev properties.
env = os.getenv('ENV', 'dev')
if env == 'dev':
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'some super secret key'

# for server side sessions
## Commenting these two lines allows everything to work
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)


GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET")
REDIRECT_URI = '/oauth2callback'


CLIENT_CONFIG = {'web':{
    'client_id':GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID ,
    'client_secret':GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
    'redirect_uris':["http://localhost:5000/oauth2callback"],
    'auth_uri':"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    'token_uri':"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
    }}

SCOPES=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]

def generate_csrf_token():
    if '_csrf_token' not in session:
        session['_csrf_token'] = some_random_string()
    return session['_csrf_token']


def check_access_token():
    login_bypass = not os.getenv('ENFORCE_LOGIN', False)
    if login_bypass:
        return True
    return 'credentials' in session

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(CLIENT_CONFIG, scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', include_granted_scopes='true')
    session['state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)


def credentials_to_dict(credentials):
    return {'token': credentials.token,
            'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
            'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
            'client_id': credentials.client_id,
            'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
            'scopes': credentials.scopes}

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    state = session.get('state')
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(CLIENT_CONFIG, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_response = request.url
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
    credentials = flow.credentials
    id_info = jwt.decode(credentials.id_token, verify=False)
    email = id_info['email']
    #allow anyone from example.com to log in 
    if email.split('@')[1] != "example.com":
        return "Login failed!"
    session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
    session.modified = True
    #return render_template()
    return redirect(url_for('loglist'))

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/loglist")
def loglist():
    if not check_access_token():
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return "yay!"
```

after many print statements, in the deployed code, i can see that my session no longer includes the 'credentials' key so im redirected back to login.  im guessing this has something to do with DNS somewhere as it seems to work without DNS (in a way via 127.0.0.1), though i cant add private IP's to google's authorized redirect URLs to validate further.

### **Edit:**

I was able to work around this by using the cachelib module and initializing a SimpleCache()/FileSystemCache().  Not the greatest solution but it worked for me at the moment till i can put more time to figure this out.

Comment: Are you including your domain in the `CLIENT_CONFIG` `redirect_uris` when deployed?

Comment: @dylanj.nz, yes i am adding `https://example.com/oauth2callback` in the redirect_uris field as well.  I get the same redirect loop with it also.